# What is the "Dispatcher" design pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, generics

What is the "dispatcher" pattern and how would I implement it in code?

I have a property bag of generic objects and would like to have the retrieval delegated to a generic method.

Currently, I have properties looking for a specific key in the bag. For example:

```
private Dictionary<String, Object> Foo { get; set; }
private const String WidgetKey = "WIDGETKEY";

public Widget? WidgetItem
{
    get
    {
        return Foo.ContainsKey(WidgetKey) ? Foo[WidgetKey] as Widget: null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Foo.ContainsKey(WidgetKey))
            Foo[WidgetKey] = value;
        else
            Foo.Add(WidgetKey, value);
    }
}
```

It was suggested that this could be more generic with the "dispatcher" pattern, but I've been unable to find a good description or example.

I'm looking for a more generic way to handle the property bag store/retrieve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but...

> I have a property bag of generic objects and would like to have the retrieval delegated to a generic method.

... sounds like you're looking for information on "double-dispatching"?

Imagine you have three classes:

```
abstract class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

And two methods to do something with objects of type B and C:

```
void DoSomething(B obj) {}
void DoSomething(C obj) {}
```

The problem is that when all you have is a variable of static type A...:

```
A a = new B();
```

... you cannot call DoSomething(a) because at compile time only its static type (A) is known, so the compiler cannot decide if it should call method DoSomething(B obj) or DoSomething(C obj).

This is where double dispatching comes in. Some languages support it out of the box, others like C++, C# and Java don't. But you can implement it yourself in these languages as well. For an example see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

And:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: The first wikipedia article states 'In C#, multiple dispatch can be achieved without employing the visitor pattern. This is done by simply casting the object being passed to dynamic'

Comment: @DamianGreen - That quote isn't wrong, but it's very dangerous.  `dynamic` is a type that bypasses all compile-time checking, and will blow up at runtime if the type is wrong for what you're trying to do.  For example, `(int)"text"` isn't valid and won't compile, but `(int)(dynamic)"text"` is perfectly fine to the compiler, and will raise an exception when the code gets there.   There are situations where `dynamic` is needed, but they should be carefully considered.   _(Adding this much-delayed comment mostly for the sake of anyone visiting this answer in the future.)_